# How to plot Prior, Log Likelihood, and Posterior in one plot using BSTS Package from R

Tags: r, plot, bayesian

i am still learning more about bsts Package, so i am using R AirPassengers Dataset and learn to create BSTS Model along the prediction,

```
###library(lubridate)

###library(bsts)

###library(dplyr)

###library(ggplot2)

###Load the data

data("AirPassengers")

Y <- window(AirPassengers, start=c(1949, 1), end=c(1959,12))

ss <- AddLocalLinearTrend(list(), Y)

ss <- AddSeasonal(ss, Y, nseasons = 12)

bsts.model <- bsts(Y, state.specification = ss, niter = 500, ping=0, seed=2016)

burn <- SuggestBurn(0.1, bsts.model)

p <- predict.bsts(bsts.model, horizon = 12, burn = burn, quantiles = c(.025, .975))
```

i found that when i look bsts.model further, bsts.model$prior return me something like this

[Prior returning only 1 value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kpNn.png)

then `bsts.model$log.likelihood`

[BSTS Model Log.Likelihood with 500 MCMC draws](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDKWw.png)

And last p$distribution which i know as Posterior distribution is this

[Posterior distribution with 473 MCMC after burn each for month](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1T5zC.png)

and what i like to know:

Why does the prior give only this one value instead of distribution? is it possible to plot these into one picture/plot?

i checked AirPassengers dataset using EasyFit software, then the result it is fitted to Beta Distribution with these parameter ibb.co/dxwrvm but i wanted to know more if i can do these using R..

Thankyou in Advance

**[Edit--18 Nov 2017]--------------------------------------------------------**

below i can only plotting between the likelihood and the posterior, because i still can't get the idea where the prior came from:

plot(density(p$distribution))

lines(density(AirPassengers),type="l")

[Result Plotting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUvfY.png)

if i define my own prior, i will use random t distribution with rt(1000,12,650)
where it generate 1000 iteration, with df=12, and central line=650, it will match the entire plot graph like this:

drawt = rt(1000,12,650)

lines(density(drawt))

[with own prior definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uY5sj.png)

so its clearly see that this prior(right side) x likelihood(left side) ever create these posterior distribution, BUT the bsts package can generate posterior without i am defining any prior.. can someone help me explain this?

(i already search state.specification that is mentioned by Steve but it just give me some list of prior.guess of trend and seasonal, and its still hard for me to understand where is the prior distribution came of, if there's way,please give me more real example in code for this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i lately do lot of research with trial and errors and googling,
and i found this research using bayesian more useful than others i ever see

http://sisifospage.tech/2017-10-30-forecasting-bsts.html

and i make my own conclusion that to predict these (prior, data likelihood, posterior) into one plot like this:

**plot(density(bsts.model$one.step.prediction.error),xlim=c(-100,1000),ylim=c(0,0.035))** // these denotes the prior i assume

**lines(density(p$distribution))** // these denotes posterior distribution

**lines(density(AirPassengers))** // these denotes data likelihood

and the result i get something like this:

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyNkd.png)

Still **[Correct me if i am wrong]**

i read in R help about Prior and i found these statement [If the model contains no regressors, then this is simply the prior on the residual standard deviation, expressed as an object created by SdPrior.] but SdPrior is only numeric object,

and sisifospage.tech does give detail explanation how to use SdPrior to make a trend Component, i then know that these SdPrior and its siblings is meant to create prior as parameter for the trend Component, and the final result is contained in the bsts model in one.step.prediction.error as the analysis residual.

Answer (score 0):

The prior is the prior on the observation variance.  It is an inverse gamma distribution with prior.guess as a guess at the standard deviation, and prior.df as the prior sample size.  See the help page for SdPrior.

I'm not sure what you mean by "beta distribution".  The beta distribution is a distribution on [0, 1] (i.e. that is its support).  You might mean "distribution on the 'beta's" (i.e. the regression coefficients), but that wouldn't make sense in this example because the model you've fit has no regression coefficients.

Also note that there are (independent) prior distributions for the parameters of the state models.  Since both state models you've used are combinations of random walks, the only parameters for these models are the variances of the respective error terms in the random walks, so these will also be gamma distributions.  You can find these prior distributions by examining bsts.model$state.specification.  It is a copy of the state.specification argument you passed in the bsts call.  In your case it is a list with two elements, one for each component of state (the trend, and the seasonal).

Comment: Thankyou Sir, i noted your reply, i did searched bsts.model$state.specification as you said Mr Steve, and i got these in summary: http://ibb.co/dJGuqw , can you explain some more explanation what is the difference between one and another? i mean something like what is the differ initial.level.prior with initial.slope.prior? and so on.. is this referring to regression coefficients? thankyou sir Steve